# Get query string from data jpa for debug

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have usually JpaRepository.

There are several types of queries in it.
made with

- **JPA**
- **JPQL**
- **HQL**

It occurred to me to see if they were doing unnecessary actions. I have enabled SQL query debug. Requests began to be output to my console.

I want to write a test for queries so that they do not contain **join** when it is not needed.

How can I get the string that Hibernate (or Spring Data JPA) generates.
Maybe there are other ways to find such dangerous situations in the code?

Comment: What's a JPA query? Do you mean a Criteria Query?

Comment: @Knox I mean "findOneByIdAnd....."

Comment: I see. Those are Spring Data Query Methods. They aren't _directly_ tied to JPA, but under the hood, they are implemented as JPA Criteria Queries.